# Removing "MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected" nodejs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, node.js

I'm using WebTorrent-hybrid (https://github.com/webtorrent/webtorrent-hybrid) on my linux ubuntu server (32GB Ram / Intel i7) and I want seed a lot of files.

I'm using this command:

```
webtorrent-hybrid seed <folder> --keep-seeding
```

This command works fine! But I'm getting these messages:

```
(node:1584) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 connection listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:1584) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 request listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:1584) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 data listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:1584) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:1584) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

My terminal is flooded by this! I saw at forums that this is just a warning! But I think that this warning is crashing my application, because the files is not being seeded.

So, this application is nodejs based but I can't to solve this issue using node itself, since its a terminal command. Are there an way to set this limit to infinity on terminal?

Thank you!